# Where can I find uWSGI v2.1? It's not on pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, uwsgi

In the uWSGI documentation there are [multiple](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) [references](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PHP.html) to version `2.1`. (Search for "2.1" in those links.)

However, I can't seem to *find* `uWSGI==2.1`! [Pypi seems to only have up to version `2.0.18`](https://pypi.org/project/uWSGI/).

What gives?

Comment: Upon do more research it seems that 2.1 is taking an inordinate amount of time (years!?) to release: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2037

Comment: Hypothesis: they updated the documentation before releasing the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by a semi-recent [Github comment](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2037#issuecomment-640167887) of the(?) uwsgi author, a release of v2.1 is not planned / not in sight due to what sounds like maintainability issues; important features will be backported.